# Align table side by side in html email template

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic data based on which I need to show them in the email template. I used the following code to align table side by side but it is not working. I use this table inside the loop so that same table repeat again and make the layout. There is also a parent table outside of the loop to contain this dynamic table but i didn't write those code here. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```html
<table align="left" style="width:50%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="left" style="width:50%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="left" style="width:50%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask. If you are trying show data based on a condition then put an if statement inside your loop and when the condition is met echo or print that table. We really need more info. What [language] what [conditions] what [data]

Comment: Language is dotnet, but my requirement is get data from api and based on that data send email to user. Data is of JSON format which contain name and email. For rendering data in email template I am running a loop and inside a loop I need a wrappers component to hold this data that is why I use this table component as I need my data in two columns layout which is not possible if I use td elements as it creates lots of columns.

Comment: Please include your dotnet code in your question. The more information we have the better we can help you. we are flying blind and you will not get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3th table is on the 2nd line becauses the first 2 are taking up 100% of the space.A solution is to remove the width style all together if you are using a loop to add the tables you can devide the 100 by the number of tables to get the width.

```html
<table align="left">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="left">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table align="left">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Loop migth be like this

```
for(var i = 0;i<num;i++){
...
table.style.width = (100 / num) + "%";
...
};
```

Is this what you are after?

UPDATE

a better alternative migth be to make all the tables in to one like this.I think it should work on outlook.

```html
<table align="left" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Would this work?

Comment: Can't we give 50% width to each table so that we always see two table in a row and next table automatically start in upcoming row?

Comment: I think that should work dose it not?

Comment: In browser it is working fine but in Outlook it is coming as full width whenever I add any custom width to my table

Comment: maby some thing like this migth work let me add some thing to my post